# Почему я не могу подключиться к MySQL | Python

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

Появилась необходимость быстро прыгать на новую для меня технологию (mySQL), мне скинули исходники, я попытался подключиться к БД по предоставленным мне данным. Но я получаю ошибку, при попытке создать "обьект подключения"

```py
def connect_to_db():
    # создание подключения к базе данных
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        database="данные я убрал",
        host="данные я убрал",
        user="данные я убрал",
        password=f"данные я убрал",
    )
```

Ошибка:

```
1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fcxfre6o_u632961'@'136.169.169.126' (using password: YES)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'fcxfre6o_u632961'@'136.169.169.126' (using password: YES)
```

С чем это может быть связано ?

Comment: с настройками самого сервера mysql. например, он запрещает подключения с иного, кроме localhost хоста.

Comment: Но ведь написано: "Access denied" ! Идите к сисадмину Вашей СУБД и пускай он настраивает Ваш допуск к БД.

Answer (score 0):

Можно было и в гугл постучать :) Без обид

Google:
Эта ошибка обычно возникает, когда пользователь пытается получить доступ к базе данных, используя неверные учетные данные или неверный пароль. Возможно, пароль был изменен, и пользователь не обновил его в своем приложении или скрипте. Также возможно, что имя пользователя было набрано неправильно или пользователь не имеет прав доступа к базе данных.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, необходимо убедиться, что имя пользователя и пароль введены правильно, и что пользователь имеет правильные разрешения для доступа к базе данных. Если пароль был изменен, то его необходимо обновить в приложении или скрипте. Кроме того, можно проверить, есть ли ограничения доступа к базе данных, такие как IP-адреса, которые могут получить доступ к базе данных, и убедиться, что IP-адрес, используемый пользователем, разрешен для доступа к базе данных.